# Accessing Class inside of source file for inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

Hello I am trying to access a class inside of my source file Appointment, in order to gain access to Time and Date. My problem is that when I do this, as soon as I switched tabs the inheritance delinks and can no longer find Appointment.

This is my source file.

```
class Appointment
{
   protected:
Date date;
Time start_time, end_time;
char description[40], location[40];
   public:
Appointment();
void get();
void print() const;
Date get_date() const;
Time get_start_time() const;
Time get_end_time() const;
    };
```

This is the class in which I am trying to inherit Appointment from.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using std::ostream;
    using std::istream;
    #ifndef Session_H 
    #define Session_H 
    class Session : public Appointment
{
    protected:
  string client_id, fname, lname;
  int charge;
    public:
Session();
string get();
string get_id() const;
string get_fname() const;
string get_lname() const;
int calc_charge();
~Session();
};
#endif
```

Comment: "My problem is that when I do this, as soon as I switched tabs the inheritance delinks and can no longer find Appointment." what does that suppose to mean exactly ??

Comment: You have time and date accesssors as public, so you don't need to inherit to access them !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the source file:

```
#ifndef Session_H 
#define Session_H 
#include <iostream>
#include "Appointment.h" // or whatever the source file is named

// These really shouldn't be here (namespace pollution)    
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using std::string;

class Session : public Appointment
{
protected:
string client_id, fname, lname;
int charge;
public:
Session();
string get();
string get_id() const;
string get_fname() const;
string get_lname() const;
int calc_charge();
~Session();
};
#endif
```

Also, notice that the include guards belong at the very top of the file, before anything else (to ensure that absolutely everything within it is protected from repeated inclusion). In other words, *any* file that is to be used as a header should have include guards. Period.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of how things might be laid out more properly:

```
 // Appointment.h   

#ifndef Appointment_H 
#define Appointment_H 
#include "Chronos.h" // Or wherever your Date and Time objects are defined

class Appointment
{
    protected:
    Date date;
    Time start_time, end_time;
    char description[40], location[40];
    public:
    Appointment();
    void get();
    void print() const;
    Date get_date() const;
    Time get_start_time() const;
    Time get_end_time() const;
};
#endif


// Session.h    


#ifndef Session_H 
#define Session_H 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Appointment.h" 

// These really shouldn't be here (namespace pollution)...
using std::string;    
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;

class Session : public Appointment
{
protected:
    string client_id, fname, lname;
    int charge;
public:
    Session();
    string get();
    string get_id() const;
    string get_fname() const;
    string get_lname() const;
    int calc_charge();
    ~Session();
};
#endif

// main.cpp    

#include "Session.h" 

int main()
{
    Session session;
}
```

Comment: Thank you however, the appointment class is located in the same file as main and thus is .cpp file.

Comment: Okay, so your code organization is all wrong. You're not supposed to include .cpp files from a header. It should be something like this: